# Defining algebra on Proc

Tags: ruby, proc, boolean-operations

I am trying to define conjunction `Proc#*` and disjunction `Proc#+` on `Proc` class. When the receiver and the argument have different arity, then it should raise an error. Otherwise, it should return a proc object that is conjunction/disjunction, respectively. I implemented them as follows:

```
class Proc
  def * other
    raise ArgumentError, "Arity does not match" unless arity == other.arity
    ->(*args){call(*args) and other.call(*args)}
  end
  def + other
    raise ArgumentError, "Arity does not match" unless arity == other.arity
    ->(*args){call(*args) or other.call(*args)}
  end
end
```

This works well with simple procs:

```
p = ->x{x % 2 == 0} * ->x{x % 3 == 0}
p.call(2) # => false
p.call(6) # => true
```

but it raises an error when I further try to build on the result of these methods:

```
q = p * ->x{x % 5 == 0}
# => Error, Arity does not match
```

This is because the arity of `->x{x % 5 == 0}` is `1`, whereas the arity of `p` is `-1` due to `call(*args)` in my implementation.

Is there any good way to make the methods `Proc#*` and `Proc#+` work recursively?

---

If I remove the `raise ...` from the definition, then it will work, but then, it will return misleading error messages when procs with different arity are conjoined/disjoined. For example, suppose the `raise ...` part is deleted from the definition above, and I do:

```
p = ->x{x % 2 == 0} * ->x, y, z{x % 3 == 0}
```

then `Proc#*` will not raise an error, but will return a valid proc object. However, since part of it requires one argument and another part requires three arguments, there would be no way to pass arguments to `p` in a valid way.

```
p.call(2) # => error
```

will raise an `ArgumentError`, saying:

```
Wrong number of arguments
```

but the mistake actually happened when creating `p` that cannot be satisfied with any number of arguments, and the error message would be misleading. That is why I added the `raise ...` check. Is removing the `raise ...` only way to make it work?

Comment: You are using lambda here, when you could use Proc and not rely so much on a "valid arity" as Procs will not raise for that reason.  But lambda does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need to remove the `raise` because procs that take variable numbers of arguments can be validly called but have different arity values. For example

```
p = ->(a) {} * (a, *args) {}
p.call(1)   # valid
p.call(1,2) # invalid
```

Maybe a solution would be to improve the error message within the returned lambda? Something like

```
lambda(*args) do
  raise "wrong number of arguments for left lambda" if (arity < 0 && arity.abs - 1 <= args.size) || (arity > 0 && arity != args.size)
  # etc (not sure those cases are exactly right)
  call(*args) and other.call(*args)
end
```

It may be easier to use the [parameters](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters) method, which will spell out the required, optional and splat parameters. Should make it easy to check if it will never be possible to call the resulting lambda and throw an error on creation in that case.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to extend `Proc`:

```
class MyProc < Proc
  attr_reader :my_arity

  def initialize(my_arity = nil, &block)
    @my_arity = my_arity || block.arity
    super(&block)
  end

  def *(other)
    other = MyProc.new(&other)
    raise "Arity error" unless my_arity == other.my_arity
    MyProc.new(my_arity, &->(*args){ call(*args) && other[*args] })
  end
end

p (MyProc.new(&->(x, y){ x == y }) * ->(x, y){ x == y } * ->(x, y){ x == y })[1,1] #=> true
p (MyProc.new(&->(x, y){ x == y }) * ->(x, y){ x == y } * ->(x, y){ x != y })[1,1] #=> false
p (MyProc.new(&->(x, y){ x == y }) * ->(x, y){ x == y } * ->(x){ x })[1,1] #=> exception
```